# Excel Validation: Named Range or User Input - Crashes

Tags: excel, validation, vlookup, named-ranges, excel-indirect

I am working on an excel problem currently which has led to a few stumbles, when I finally thought I had a working solution, excel crashes when I try to tab to the next row of the table.

The problem:

I have selection criteria to which will point the validation list to one of three options:

MSA = Lookup_MSA_Name

TSP = Lookup_TSP_Name

Other = Lookup_Blank

The top two are named ranges, I have had them assigned as dynamic and static ranges, but currently they are in a lookup table and static. Other is an option where I want to allow user input, I set the lookup to a blank cell so the validation drop down isn't giving options.

The code I placed in the validation cell set to list, unticked the error message tab and is:

```
   =(IF($C$7="MSA",Lookup_MSA_Name,IF($C$7="TSP",Lookup_TSP_Name,Lookup_Blank)))
```

This seems to work perfectly, but crashes excel (2016 and 2010) when I tab the next row down in the table.

Previous to this, I was using an indirect formula (named ranges were the same as the original drop down (MSA=MSA, TSP=TSP, Other=Other).

The indirect formula worked when a drop down selection was made, but when tabbing the next cell, the formula got messed up and the drop down would no longer work if user input or paste occured into the cell, I used the examples from the following site to build the formula:

http://www.contextures.com/xlDataVal02.html

The big stumble from both approaches seems to be down to being able to offer user input and drop down selection. Hoping for some guidance on what I am missing..

Comment: Please clarify "Crashes Excel" (VBA runtime error or Excel process crash) and "tabbing the next cell"?

Comment: Excel actually crashes, the screen goes white and it says excel has stopped working, restart or close the application. There is no VBA runtime error. I have tried removing the validation altogether than it no longer occurs, so it is something which lies with the validation criteria. Tabbing the next cell, as in the values are stored in a table so when you tab the last cell of the table it tries to create a new row within the table.